# How to label multiple objects in one plot?

Tags: plotting, color, labeling

I am struggling to label curves in my Plot while using Manipulate and specific function already mentioned here.

```
Manipulate[Grid[{{Plot[{(-2 m \[Beta] - Sqrt[
       p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
        4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])/(2 m), (
      2 m \[Beta] - Sqrt[
       p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
        4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])/(
      2 m), (-2 m \[Beta] + Sqrt[
       p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
        4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])/(2 m), (
      2 m \[Beta] + Sqrt[
       p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
        4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])/(2 m)}, {p, -20, 30}, 
     MultiColorFunction[
      Function[p, 
       ColorData["Rainbow"][
        Rescale[(-p^2 + 2 m \[Mu] + Sqrt[
           p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
            4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])^2/(
         4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 (1 + 
            1/4 Abs[(-p^2 + 2 m \[Mu] + Sqrt[
               p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
                4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])/(m \[CapitalDelta])]^2)), {-1, 1}]]], 
      Function[p, 
       ColorData["Rainbow"][
        Rescale[-((p^2 - 2 m \[Mu] - Sqrt[
            p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
             4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])^2/(
          4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 (1 + 
             1/4 Abs[(
               p^2 - 2 m \[Mu] - Sqrt[
                
                p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
                 4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])/(m \[CapitalDelta])]^2))), {-1, 
          1}]]], Function[p, 
       ColorData["Rainbow"][
        Rescale[(-p^2 + 2 m \[Mu] - Sqrt[
           p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
            4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])^2/(
         4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 (1 + 
            1/4 Abs[(-p^2 + 2 m \[Mu] - Sqrt[
               p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
                4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])/(m \[CapitalDelta])]^2)), {-1, 1}]]], 
      Function[p, 
       ColorData["Rainbow"][
        Rescale[-((p^2 - 2 m \[Mu] + Sqrt[
            p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
             4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])^2/(
          4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 (1 + 
             1/4 Abs[(
               p^2 - 2 m \[Mu] + Sqrt[
                p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
                 4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])/(m \[CapitalDelta])]^2))), {-1, 
          1}]]]], PlotRange -> {-300, 300}, AxesLabel -> {p, H[p]}, 
     LabelStyle -> "ItemNumbered", 
     PlotLabels -> Placed[{"a", "b", "c", "d"}, {Scaled[1], Top}], 
     Background -> GrayLevel[.8]], 
    Plot[{(-p^2 + 2 m \[Mu] + Sqrt[
        p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
         4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])^2/(
      4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 (1 + 
         1/4 Abs[(-p^2 + 2 m \[Mu] + Sqrt[
            p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
             4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])/(m \[CapitalDelta])]^2)), -((p^2 - 
         2 m \[Mu] - Sqrt[
         p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
          4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])^2/(
       4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 (1 + 
          1/4 Abs[(
            p^2 - 2 m \[Mu] - Sqrt[
             p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
              4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])/(m \[CapitalDelta])]^2))), (-p^2 + 
        2 m \[Mu] - Sqrt[
        p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
         4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])^2/(
      4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 (1 + 
         1/4 Abs[(-p^2 + 2 m \[Mu] - Sqrt[
            p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
             4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])/(m \[CapitalDelta])]^2)), -((p^2 - 
         2 m \[Mu] + Sqrt[
         p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
          4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])^2/(
       4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 (1 + 
          1/4 Abs[(
            p^2 - 2 m \[Mu] + Sqrt[
             p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
              4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])/(m \[CapitalDelta])]^2)))}, {p, -10, 
      10}, MultiColorFunction[
      Function[p, 
       ColorData["Rainbow"][
        Rescale[(-p^2 + 2 m \[Mu] + Sqrt[
           p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
            4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])^2/(
         4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 (1 + 
            1/4 Abs[(-p^2 + 2 m \[Mu] + Sqrt[
               p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
                4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])/(m \[CapitalDelta])]^2)), {-1, 1}]]], 
      Function[p, 
       ColorData["Rainbow"][
        Rescale[-((p^2 - 2 m \[Mu] - Sqrt[
            p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
             4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])^2/(
          4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 (1 + 
             1/4 Abs[(
               p^2 - 2 m \[Mu] - Sqrt[
                p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
                 4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])/(m \[CapitalDelta])]^2))), {-1, 
          1}]]], Function[p, 
       ColorData["Rainbow"][
        Rescale[(-p^2 + 2 m \[Mu] - Sqrt[
           p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
            4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])^2/(
         4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 (1 + 
            1/4 Abs[(-p^2 + 2 m \[Mu] - Sqrt[
               p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
                4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])/(m \[CapitalDelta])]^2)), {-1, 1}]]], 
      Function[p, 
       ColorData["Rainbow"][
        Rescale[-((p^2 - 2 m \[Mu] + Sqrt[
            p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
             4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])^2/(
          4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 (1 + 
             1/4 Abs[(
               p^2 - 2 m \[Mu] + Sqrt[
                p^4 + 4 m^2 \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 4 m p^2 \[Mu] + 
                 4 m^2 \[Mu]^2])/(m \[CapitalDelta])]^2))), {-1, 
          1}]]]], PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {p, S_ {z}[p]}, 
     AxesLabel -> {p, H[p]}, LabelStyle -> "ItemNumbered"]}}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {\[Beta], 0, 100}, {\[Mu], -5, 
  100}, {m, 0.51099895}, {\[CapitalDelta], 0.1, 100}]
```

The main aim of this manipulate is to create two plots, each possessing 4 curves. The colour of the curves on the first graph are related to the values of  the curves at the second one by function:

```
MultiColorFunction /: (h : (Plot | Plot3D))[{fs__}, before___, 
  MultiColorFunction[cf__], after___] := 
 Show[h[#1, before, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
     ColorFunction -> #2, after] & @@@ Transpose[{{fs}, {cf}}]]
```

It looks like this:[image]
Now I am struggling with function `PlotLables`, it seems there is a mismatch between labeling and colouring the function. I would like to label each curve/function in the first plot like E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4, but when I write

```
PlotLabels->{"E_1","E_2","E_3","E_4"}
```

it tooks just the first element and assigns it to each curve/function. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I think the example you are providing is quite large; I have some trouble reproducing your pictures with it. Since I think we can agree that in the simplest cases the `PlotLabels` work as expected, could you reduce the code to a [minimum working example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example)?

Comment: a simpler example showing the same issue: `Manipulate[
 Plot[{Sin[a x], Cos[a x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  MultiColorFunction[Red &, Green &], 
  PlotLabels -> Placed[{"Sin", "Cos"}, {Scaled[1/2], Top}]], {a, 1, 
  5}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the way `UpValues` for `MultiColorFunction` are defined, options (such as `PlotLabels`, `PlotStyle`, `Filling` and possibly others) that might set values for multiple functions will cause the same issue as illustrated below using a simpler example:

```
Manipulate[Plot[{Sin[a x], Cos[a x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotLabels -> Placed[{"Sin", "Cos"}, {Scaled[1/2], Top}]],
{{a, 3}, 1, 5}]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[Plot[{Sin[a x], Cos[a x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  MultiColorFunction[Red &, Green &], 
  PlotLabels -> Placed[{"Sin", "Cos"}, {Scaled[1/2], Top}]], 
{{a, 3}, 1, 5}]
```

[image]

**A work-around:** Without changing `MultiColorFunction` we can fix the `PlotLabels` issue easily: Remove the option `PlotLabels` and wrap input functions with `Callout` or with `Labeled` to inject the labels:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate @ MapThread[Callout[#, #2, {Scaled[1/2], Top}] &, 
    {{Sin[a x], Cos[a x]}, {"Sin", "Cos"}}], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  MultiColorFunction[Red &, Green &]], {{a, 3}, 1, 5}]
```

[image]

Additional issues illustrated in the following examples can only be fixed with a complete re-write of `MultiColorFunction`:

```
Manipulate[Plot[{Sin[a x], Cos[a x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Dotted], Directive[Thick, Dashing[Large]]}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {Top, Yellow}, 2 -> {Bottom, Cyan}}, 
  PlotLabels -> Placed[{"Sin", "Cos"}, {Scaled[1/2], Top}]], 
 {{a, 3}, 1, 5}]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[Plot[{Sin[a x], Cos[a x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  MultiColorFunction[Red &, Green &], 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Dotted], Directive[Thick, Dashing[Large]]}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {Top, Yellow}, 2 -> {Bottom, Cyan}}, 
  PlotLabels -> Placed[{"Sin", "Cos"}, {Scaled[1/2], Top}]],
{{a, 3}, 1, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems working properly even in my a little bit more complex example :)

Comment: @TimonMoško, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.